# Angular 6 Material - Change the separator in mat-select multiple options

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select in my form with multiple options ([You can see a demo in here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)).

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

It shows a comma-separated list of selected options in its input field. Is there any way to change the separator?

Comment: Code is missing. Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that is responsible for that separator could be found here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/9f6aa843cd2f68562d3f5290688bbe5bab957bcf/src/lib/select/select.ts#L642

```
// TODO(crisbeto): delimiter should be configurable for proper localization.
return selectedOptions.join(', ');
```

As you can see it is not supported yet. **But**
there is another way to achieve it.

Just add custom `mat-select-trigger` as below:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple ...>
    ...
    <mat-select-trigger>
        <span> {{toppings.value ? toppings.value.join('; ') : ''}}</span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
</mat-select>
```

**[Forked Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw-tkxkbm?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)**

So that you can choose any separator, for example:

```
toppings.value.join('&#9832;')
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, and what if I send the index of the topping to the value attr?
Then I just can't use toppings.value b/c it's just numbers! Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw-estafb?file=app/select-multiple-example.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw-8huk39?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts I used getter here but maybe the better solution would be using pure pipe to avoid redundant calculation

Comment: Sure, Thanks. 
Again, you're awesome! :)

Comment: Here's an example with pipe https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw-kejfrh?file=app/select-multiple-example.html

Comment: Works like a charm :)